# Powershell loop

Tags: powershell

I'd like to loop to commands with `powershell` for creating local share and remove it after 5 minutes. Then wait 1 minute and create the share again.. Then after 5 minutes to remove it and after another one minute to create it again and so on and so forth ..

Got those two:

```
$FolderPath = "D:\proxy"
$ShareName = "proxy"
$Type = 0

$objWMI = [wmiClass] 'Win32_share'
$objWMI.create($FolderPath, $ShareName, $Type)

Start-Sleep -s 60
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Share -Filter "Name='proxy'" | Remove-WmiObject

Start-Sleep -s 60
$objWMI = [wmiClass] 'Win32_share'
$objWMI.create($FolderPath, $ShareName, $Type)
```

But it's not looping. It stops after end of file.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the last creation step, in a loop it will be created in the first loop step. To cancel the operation, press CTRL+C.

```
$FolderPath = "D:\proxy"
$ShareName = "proxy"
$Type = 0

while($true){
    #create the share
    $objWMI = [wmiClass] 'Win32_share'
    $objWMI.create($FolderPath, $ShareName, $Type)

    # remove it after 5 minutes
    Start-Sleep -s 300
    Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Share -Filter "Name='proxy'" | Remove-WmiObject

    # wait one minute, share will be created in next loop iteration
    Start-Sleep -s 60
}
```

Comment: Worked perfectly for me.

Answer (score 0):

Simply insert your code to `do {} while(true)` block (or change the condition to whatever you need)

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
$done = $false
while(!$done)
{
    $FolderPath = "D:\proxy"
$ShareName = "proxy"
$Type = 0

$objWMI = [wmiClass] 'Win32_share'
$objWMI.create($FolderPath, $ShareName, $Type)

Start-Sleep -s 60
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Share -Filter "Name='proxy'" | Remove-WmiObject

Start-Sleep -s 60
$objWMI = [wmiClass] 'Win32_share'
$objWMI.create($FolderPath, $ShareName, $Type)
}
```